# HAProxy load balancing

Tags: cluster-computing, haproxy, percona

Is there a way to configure HAProxy to stop sending queries to one of the nodes in a percona xtradb cluster if that node is running a very slow query i.e, bypassing the node processing the extremely slow query and send only to the other nodes until the node processing the extremely slow query becomes free?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the HAProxy monitoring script to consider long running queries in it's decision making process. This is not something that can be done via any built-in means; it would be completely custom written.